# Rider unable to find installed .NET Core, can't access the directory with MSBuild.dll

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm using Pop OS 21.04. Executed all of the code written on Microsoft Docs to install .NET Core properly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

It has installed. `dotnet --info` provides me with the SDK installation directory which is `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.301/` but Rider can't autodetect neither CLI executable, nor the MSBuild. When I try to manually put the installation path there, it doesn't show all of the present directories. I can clearly see using the explorer that the file is there. Rider just doesn't seem to be able to access the directories for some reason. What is wrong and how can I make Rider work?

[image: Screenshot showing that Rider doesn't show all of the directories]

[image: Screenshot showing that the file is in fact present in the directory]

Comment: Report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue as you although I'm using Manjaro-KDE and I was able to fix it by uninstalling Rider and installing from a different source.

For some reason this seems to be an issue unique to the flatpak version. I have tried installing Rider via AUR and via the Jetbrains Toolbox application and both work without issue (all versions of the application were 2021.3.2).

So from what I can tell it's something to do with how flatpak installs the application, so could also be the same with snap although I haven't tried this.